# css :checked - change id's background color

Tags: html, css

Here are selectors:

```
<label for="choise1" id="l1"></label>
<label for="choise2" id="l2"></label>
<input type="radio" id="choise1" name="navinp" checked="true" />
<input type="radio" id="choise2" name="navinp" />
```

and css:

```
#choise1:checked ~#l1 
{  background-color: #fff;  }

#choise2:checked ~#l2 
{  background-color: #fff;  }
```

I supposed this should change lables `bgcolor` but nothing happens when clicking over labels.
What's wrong?

Comment: what browser are you using?  This isn't supported in IE

Answer (score 4):

The `~` selector doesn't work for the elements preceding the current one.

If you want to highlight the labels then they must come **after** the checkboxes - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/RnbQ3/)

Answer (score 0):

This may be a browser issue since the Psuedo class selector :checked is not supported by Internet Explorer.

Reference: http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-checked

Comment: It works fine for me in IE9. I think sitepoint needs to update their compatibility tables, they don't even mention IE9.

Comment: It breaks in IE8, so depending on what you support this may or may not be a viable solution.

Comment: I'm jealous of you guys who get to use fancy CSS, I'm obligated to support IE7 still. And by "support" I mean "everything must work exactly the same"...

Comment: @Wesley Murch on one of my projects at work we are still using Quirks Mode and supporting IE7 - IE9